# Springboot not reading external Property file

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables, properties-file

Trying to read property in SpringBoot application through external property file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"file:${DOCUMENT_CONVERTER_PROPERTIES}"})
public class ConverterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConverterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

here, DOCUMENT_CONVERTER_PROPERTIES is the place holder for file
F:\PROPPERTIES\converter\documentConverter.properties added in evironment variable.

ConverterService.java

```
@Service
public class ConverterService {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    String tempPDFPath = environment.getProperty(Constants.TEMP_PDF_PATH);
    String tempDocxPath = environment.getProperty(Constants.TEMP_DOCX_PATH);
```

ConverterServiceTest.java

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
//@TestPropertySource("classpath:/")
public class ConverterServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ConverterService service;
    private byte[] bytes = null;

    @Test
    void testConvertDocxToPDF(){
        createFile("<path>/myFile.docx"); //put this file at given location
        service.convertDocxToPDF(bytes);
    }
```

what missing here, any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is building URIs in Windows.
Your PropertySource results in

`file:F:\PROPPERTIES\converter\documentConverter.properties`.

I think the correct format is

`file:///F:/PROPPERTIES/converter/documentConverter.properties`

Backslashes in the path may work, but the slashes at the start (`file:///`) are mandatory...